# Serre's proof of $ \operatorname{Br}(K/k) = H^2(K/k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, brauer-group

I am reading Serre's proof on the Galois cohomological interpretation of the Brauer group, i.e. on the isomorphism $ \operatorname{Br}(K/k) \to H^2(K/k)$ (Serre, Local Fields, X, § 5).

In Proposition 9, he claims it is already shown that the defined map $A(K/k) \to H^2(K/k)$ is injective.

This is clear to me for $A(n, K/k) \to H^2(K/k)$ from the long exact cohomology sequence. However I do not see why, taking the union over all $n$ yields an injective map too.

Seems to be a very simple argument I am missing, I appreciate your help.

**Edit:** this boils down to a statement like the following:

If C and D are central simple k-algebras, not necessarily of the same dimension, with $C \otimes D^{op}$ isomorphic to a matrix algebra over k, then $C \cong D$.

Is this statement correct?

Comment: For the question in the edit: yes, just tensor with $D$ and use that $D\otimes D^{op}\cong\mathrm{End}_k(D)$

Comment: I do not see how this gives the desired result: it only yields $ C \otimes M_m(k) \cong M_r(k) \otimes D$ with $m = \mathrm{dim}_k D$, $r^2 = m \mathrm{dim}_k C$. However I only need that $C$ and $D$ are isomorphic to matrix algebras over the same division algebra as indicated below.

Comment: Okay, I mistakenly took $\cong$ for brauer equivalence. But I don't see why you would need that to show $Br(K/k)\cong H^2(K/k)$. The proof I know only uses straightforward facts on crossed products and their factor systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the uniqueness of the inverse element in the classical definition of the Brauer group (via equivalence classes of central simple algebras).

See for example: Kersten, Ina: Brauergruppen von Körpern as a German language reference.